# How to sort an array which alternates monotonically

Tags: arrays, sorting

There is an array which is monotonically increasing for some time, then decreasing, again increasing, ...etc, like `[1,2,3,4,5,3,1,-1,-3,2,5,67,90,8,7,3,0]`. What would be the best way to sort this array? Some related question in Stackoverflow suggested `K-Way Merge Sort`, although no implementation details were provided.

So what would be the ideal way to sort it? Will any slick method provide significantly better performance than the good old `O(N*log N)` given by `quicksort`, so as to merit its use? If `K-Way Merge Sort` is the thing to do, please provide some implementation detail, I couldn't find one on Internet!

Comment: If you were on .Net , you have to do only Array.Sort(); I think you are in some unmanaged environment..

Comment: Come on now! Every language provides a `sort` function, does that mean we should never study and learn sorting algorithms?

Comment: @H2CO3, Preferably one from Python, Perl, PHP, C. If you can't do in any of these, any other will do too, just include sufficient comments, please!

Comment: @Cupidvogel C stdlib has `qsort()` which is very well-optimized on most modern systems. Does it suffice?

Comment: This is a micro-optimization. Chances are unless your array is enormous and you know where the regions are, any overhead you incur specializing this sort will be larger than the performance gain.

Comment: It's an interview question, so ours not to reason why, ours but to micro-optimize, even if it is not worth it!

Comment: Here you go, top hit in google for [K-Way Merge Sort](http://code.google.com/p/kway/)

Comment: Exploiting natural runs in real-world data is indeed what is done in Python's standard sorting algorithm, [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).

Comment: @amdn that requires all the subarrays to be sorted in the required order. That's not good enough for this question.

Comment: @icepack, you are right, like you suggested do an O(n) pass to reverse the descending ones... or, keep a flag in each subarray that indicates which end is the `head`.

Answer (score 1):

You want [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), which exploits natural runs.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose a natural mergesort with preprocessing will do it in O(n).

1. Reverse the order in the descending subarrays - O(n) total
2. Do a natural mergesort - O(n): http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Merge_sort#Natural_mergesort